# Cake PHP Form Flexibilty

Tags: cakephp, twitter-bootstrap

I want to replicate the html that the cakephp form helper creates, so i can add to it and integrate it into my bootstrap front end. Basically the cakephp form helper isnt generating the html I need.

Someone else built the app using cake forms, and I dont want to rewrite the backend.

I thought it would simply be a case of including the correct input names, form classes etc, and building upon it. It seems however that even an exact copy/paste of the form html doesnt trigger the cakephp form errors.

It sends identical headers to cake, 
http://pastebin.com/JZyCk6cv 
so I can only assume that the cakephp form helper does some jiggery pokery when its constructed in the template, in order to trigger validation errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best solution is to create a custom CakePHP-Helper. If you're using twitter-bootstrap i recommend this Helper, packed as a plugin:

https://github.com/loadsys/twitter-bootstrap-helper

Form validation should work, as it uses CakePHP's core form-helper to create inputs and labels.

Maybe you don't have to rewrite or edit much if you use search and replace (replace `$this->Form->input` by `$this->TwitterBootstrap->input`).

Comment: I think its a trade off between the amount of code I'll need to write with a custom helper and how often I'll need to use it. I've decided to go the route of custom html with the relevant field names, and then manual handling of the errors that the model generates.